# display the first letter of every word in a string having spaces

Tags: c, arrays, character, space

I am trying to display the first letter of every word in this C program. However, it is not recognizing the spaces in my given input. I'm printing a line inside the if statement as a debugging measure. However, that line is not being executed. It is only outputting the first element of the input. Thanks in advance!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void stringg(char s[],int size)
{
        int i=1;
        char r[size];
        r[0]=s[0];
        int j;
        for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        {

                if(s[j]==' ')
                {
                        printf("Space Test \n");
                        r[i]=s[j+1];
                        i++;
                }
        }
        r[i]='\0';
        printf("\n The Returned String is %s",&r);
        return;
}
int main()
{
        char ss[100];
        scanf("%s",&ss);
        int size;
        size=sizeof(ss)/sizeof(ss[0]);
        stringg(ss,size);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: The [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function with the `"%s"` format stops reading on whitespace. Perhaps you want [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)?

Comment: Also please don't use the full size of the array as the length of the string, as the contents beyond the string terminator will not be initialized and will have *indeterminate* contents.

Comment: You can use `scanf("%[^\n]s",ss);` instead of `scanf("%s",&ss);`

Comment: `size=sizeof(ss)/sizeof(ss[0]);` -> `strlen(ss);`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks a bunch. That fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Change `sacnf("%s", &ss)` to `sacnf("%[^\n]", &ss)`

In `scanf` `%s` scans a string upto a space or a new line character.
In `sacnf("%[^\n]", &ss)` you are telling scanf to scan upto `\n`, now scanf will scan everything you give as input upto the `\n` character.
In other places you can can use this technique to scan input upto a specific character. Just replace the `\n` character with desired character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C library function ' isspace() '. To use this function you need to open ctype library `#include <ctype.h>`. If the character is a white space (tab, vtab, new line) the function will return 1 otherwise, it returns the value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Also in cases like this one, you can use gets(); function.
The code for right string input is:

```
char txt[101] = {0}, *ptr;

 printf("Message: \n"); // note \n
 gets(txt);

 ptr = (char*)calloc( strlen(txt)+1, sizeof(char)); 
// note + 1 we need byte space for '\0' character 

strcpy(ptr, txt);
```